# managing XCP using xenopenmanager

Tags: virtualization

ubuntu server 12.10 64bit.

i installed the xen server using the "apt-get install xcp-xapi"

trying to connect to host using openxenmanager but it keeps on giving me "[Errno 11] connection refused".

ping & ssh is working.

don't know what could be the problem

best regards

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. A not so elegant but working solution, is to use ssh tunneling to connect to the Xen server like this:

```
ssh -L 8080:localhost80 <ip-of-xcp-server>
```

After you connected, instruct your OpenXenManager to connect to "localhost" and port 8080.
Use your root username and password and you are in.